# Graph Api Friends Data Inconsistency

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I use graph api to request the users friends data [Friends Data]:(http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=work,name), till 3-4 days back I used to get more data(work place information of my friends) than what I get now? 
Is there any update/change happened recently in Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the permission today: `friends_work_history`.